# Why to use abstract keyword in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I recently started with Ionic framework but to begin with Ionic **Angular.js**  is pre-requisite. Can any one please tell me why do we use **abstract** keyword in nested **ui-router**. I was unable to find a good tutorial on that.
Please tell me what is the significance/advantages of abstract in angular.js.

Here is the code that I am unable to understand
var app = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/todos')

  $stateProvider.state('app', {
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'main.html'
  })

  $stateProvider.state('app.todos', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/todos',
    views: {
      todos: {
        template: '<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>'
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Could you add a link?

Comment: @Sprottenwels sorry I m unable to get what u want?

Comment: it use ui-router. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views. read abstract states.

Comment: By read the questions you post, you have a very long journey ahead of you. angular have a very steep learning curve. I really understand the pressure when something new and needs to be done.
I would say you need to start with angular.js basic. so you will understand `var app = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])` which is Dependency Injection. forget about ionic and ui-router until you have understand basic angular first. angular-router is the default routing for angular which is simpler and easily understand., ui-router is a (very good) 3rd party module for routing.

Comment: @wayne Really Really thank you according to your advice I did and I got it how to do. Please post this comment as a answer. I will accept it. THANKS A LOTTTTTTT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right I will just post some of my experience using ionic.

### - Ui router parent/child scope inheritance

This is not specific to ionic. Sometimes if you want to share some common function in relation to views, by using scope inheritance, you can consolidate default/share function in the parent, or setup default states in your view, or inherit resolved dependencies.

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'main.html',
  resolve: {
    commonMeta: ["$stateParams","$http", function($stateParams, $http) {
      return $http.get("/commonMeta/" + $stateParams.id);
    }]
  },
  controller: ["$scope", function($scope) {
    // controller should be in a separate file
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.state = {};
    $scope.display = function() {
      // common logic for page display
    };
    $scope.restoreCustomerPreference = function() {
      // restore customer preference from say localstorage
    };
    $scope.init = function() {
      // 'this' will be the child $scope
      this.state = {
        error: false
      };
      this.restoreCustomerPreference();
    };
  }],
});
$stateProvider.state('app.dashboard', {
  url: '/dashboard',
  views: {
    todos: {
      template: '<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>'
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    data: ["$http", function($http) {
      return $http.get("/getDashboard/");
    }]
  },
  controller: ["$scope","commonMeta","data" function($scope,commonMeta,data) {
    // controller should be in a separate file
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.display = function() {
      // override the display logic
      $
    };
    $scope.init();
  }]
});
$stateProvider.state('app.todos', {
  url: '/todos',
  views: {
    todos: {
      template: '<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>'
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    data: ["$http", function($stateParams, $http) {
      return $http.get("/getTodos/");
    }]
  },
  controller: ["$scope", function($scope) {
    // controller should be in a separate file
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.someFn = function() {
      // some function
    };
    $scope.init();
  }]
});
```

Try to use `controller: ["$scope", function($scope) { }]` this form of dependencies injection, so your codes do not break when minified.

---

### - [ionic-slide-box](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/)

Using ionic-slide-box can develop app that user can slide left and right to get to next page, similar to facebook, by using a simple directive to fetch your template.

```
angular.module("directives",[])
.directive("slideItem", ["$http","$templateCache","$compile",function($http,$templateCache,$compile) {
  return {
    replace: false,
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: {
      template: "@"
    },
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
      var events = scope.events();

      $http.get(iAttrs.template, {cache: $templateCache})
      .success(function(result) {
        iElement.replaceWith($compile(result)(scope));                
      });

    }
  };
}]);
```

The template file can be hardcoded one:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-slide-box show-pager="false">
    <ion-slide>
      <slide-item template="templates/dashboard.html"></slide-item>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      <slide-item template="templates/todos.html"></slide-item>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      <slide-item template="templates/sumary.html"></slide-item>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slide-box>
</ion-view>
```

or using ng-repeat:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-slide-box show-pager="false">
    <ion-slide ng-repeat="o in slides">
      <slide-item template="templates/{{o.template}}.html" ></slide-item>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slide-box>
</ion-view>
```

- [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/) is a debug tool that you must have, it can debug even
  when your app is installed to a real device. without that, when your
  app start with a blank screen you just don't know what to look for.
- [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/) is a wrapper for cordova function develop by ionic
  too.
- Android device can be test easily, [TestFlight](https://www.testflightapp.com/) is good for ios
  testing.

Comment: Would you please check whether this edit is correct and incorporate it in your post? http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6329635

Answer (score 1):

When using nested states an abstract state can have child states but cannot be activated itself.

Reference:

[Nested States & Nested Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)

Comment: correct. @james, also note that `abstract` in this context is a UI-Router concept, not a core angularjs one.

Comment: @Colin Can you please ellaborate in simplest way. Reading the docs is just flying over my head I am unable to get it